# Multi-table query with mismatched fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multi-table query that fetches the values "URL" (or an alias, "Taxon") for each table. It also creates values for "MySiteID" and "MySection." This is what it looks like.

```
SELECT URL, 'GW' AS MySiteID, 'Topics' AS MySection FROM   $DBWorld.gw_topics
UNION ALL
SELECT Taxon AS URL, 'GZ' AS MySiteID, 'Life' AS MySection FROM $DBLife.gz_life_kingclass
```

The last line looks like this:

```
SELECT TopicURL AS URL, 'GS' AS MySiteID, 'Topics' AS MySection FROM  $DBSymbols.gs_top_ref
) AS Combined
WHERE Combined.URL LIKE :MyURL
```

I would like to modify the last line so it says WHERE Combined.URL LIKE :MyURL **AND G1 = 1**

In other words, a page won't display unless the value "URL" matches the page's URL and the field G1 has a value of 1.

The problem is that many of my tables don't have the field G1. I want to display everything in those particular tables.

Is there a way to modify my query so that 1) rows from a table with a field named G1 don't display unless the value for G1 is 1, and 2) rows from tables that don't have a field named G1 also display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your union:

1. on the tables that have `G1` column, add it to the select statement
2. on the tables that don't, simply add `1 as G1`

Now you have a G1 column on all, like you wanted- on the tables it comes from the table, you'll get the value from the table. on the tables you don't - it will be 1 on all rows, so it's always selected like you wanted.

After that you can add to your external where statement `AND G1 = 1`